# I would like to know some "best practices" for Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm quite new to Erlang coding and want to know what some of the "best practices" are in industry with code examples if possible.

Comment: Start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of best practices listed on Ericsson's [Programming Rules and Conventions](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml) page for Erlang.  There are many code examples.

Comment: I had never seen that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check out http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/users_guide.html The Eight Myths of Erlang Performance section is a pretty good, and short, read.

By far the best way to get a handle on erlang best practices is to peruse the source code of a couple of successful projects.  I found the [mochiweb](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/checkout) source to be especially instructive.

Comment: That 8 myths is a brilliant read! I would recommend that to  anyone considering Erlang and reading all the FUD against it! Thanks